# Explore large image collection and metadata in GEE Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine-python-api, google-colab

I usually work with Google Earth Engine from Google Colab. I am used to inspect my image collections for debugging and make sure that the processes I perform are correct.

However, I am loading an image collection from another user to which I have access but I am not able to inspect the contents of the image collection properly as I usually do:

```
col = ee.ImageCollection('users/externaluser/very_large_collection')

col
```

I obtain the following:

**ee.imagecollection.ImageCollection at 0x78f10a484550**

Initially I thought it was some problem with accessing this data but when it performed the following:

```
print('Number of images in the collection:', col.size().getInfo())
```

I obtain:

**Number of images in the collection: 917**

So I do have access to the collection. Considering that there are many images and they are very heavy (4bands and 1m resolution over a large area), is there any space limitation to inspect these objects? Is there any way to fix this or better way to inspect large objects?

For a Sentinel-2 image collection of around 150 images this works properly:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was yo limit the image collection before printing:

```
s2_col.limit(100)
```